# How to use regex with powershell to remove specific lines?

Tags: string, powershell, read-eval-print-loop, select-string

How do I remove the matched line below:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> $doc = Get-Content ./foo.txt
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> $doc                        


a
b
c
d
e
f
g
hmmm i j k l m
n
o
p
q


PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> $doc | Select-String 'h'

hmmm i j k l m

PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex>
```

this is just a sample, but would want to iterate through `$doc` removing specific lines which match.

Here, **any** line with "h" would be removed.

Looked at differently, return **all the other lines** which aren't matched.

Comment: No need for regex for identical comparisons. if `$doc` is an array, then `$doc -ne 'h i j k l m'`

Comment: $doc is a text file

Comment: Or is it a text file content? Try `$doc -split '\r?\n' | where { !$_.contains("h") }`

Comment: `Select-String -NotMatch 'h'`

Comment: `$doc = @($doc) -notmatch 'h'` will do too

Answer (score 1):

thanks to the comments:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> $doc | Select-String -notmatch 'h'



a
b
c
d
e
f
g
n
o
p
q



PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex>
```

seems to work.